# What does '&' do in C/C++ and what is its equivalent operator in perl?

Tags: c++, c, perl

I'm writing a perl implementation of a protocol whose specification is given for C/C++ but I don't know much C.

What does the condition `if ((flags & 0x400) != 0)` mean? How do I do that in perl?

Is `if ($flags == "\x400")` correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`&` is a bitwise AND. See [Bitwise operators](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/bitwise_operators.html).

So `flags` is being treated as a series of bits, and then you AND it with something which has exactly the bit set that you want to check. If the result is non-zero, then the bit is set, otherwise the bit you were looking at isn't set. In particular, in your example `0x400 = 0100 0000 0000` is being used to check if the 11th bit is set (to 1) in `flags`.

Typically, you wouldn't use `0x400` but a named constant, so it is clear what that bit represents.

So `if ($flags == "\x400")` isn't correct. See [Working with bits in Perl](http://www252.pair.com/comdog/mastering_perl/Chapters/bit_vectors.html).

A common example of bit-masking can be seen in [Linux file permissions](http://www.zzee.com/solutions/linux-permissions.shtml).

Answer (score 4):

It's the bitwise AND operator in C\C++ and Perl.

- [Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Bitwise-And)
- [C\C++](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/reference/programming/bitwise-operations-in-c-r1563)

Comment: You should link to perlop. I've seen a few people complain here about links from docstore.mik.ua because it's pirated.

Comment: @musiKk did not know that. Changed Perl related link to perlop.

Comment: Great. :) Now there are only two other answers... This is tedious. I wonder why O'Reilly doesn't do anything about it...

Answer (score 3):

The `&` operator performs a bitwise AND. In your case, `if ((flags & 0x400) != 0)` checks whether the eleventh bit of the `flags` variable is not set to 0. [You can do bitwise operations in Perl, too](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/PERL/node36.html).

Answer (score 2):

It's the [bitwise AND.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) In Perl, [the operator is "&" as well](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Bitwise-And).

Answer (score 2):

`&` is the *bitwise and* operator, basically this is a test to see if a specific bit is set in the `flags`. See the perl equivalents here: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Bitwise-And